# Pdf file saving as html file- python

Tags: python, html, pdf, beautifulsoup, python-requests

This is my code:

```
import requests
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib.request
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} 
_URL = 'http://papers.xtremepapers.com/CIE/Cambridge%20International%20A%20and%20AS%20Level/Chemistry%20%289701%29/'

r = requests.get(_URL)
soup = bs(r.text)
urls = []
names = []
for i, link in enumerate(soup.findAll('a')):
    _FULLURL = _URL + (link.get('href'))
    if _FULLURL.endswith('.pdf'):
        urls.append(_FULLURL)
        names.append(soup.select('a')[i].attrs['href'])
names_urls = zip(names, urls)

for name, url in names_urls:
    print (url)
    rq = urllib.request.Request(url,None,headers)
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(rq)
    pdf = open("pdfs/" + (name), 'wb')
    pdf.write(res.read())
    pdf.close()
    print("completed")
```

The pdfs are downloading but when I open them I get an
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jdJW.png)

PS. I'm new to python so please forgive me if this is a rookie mistake

Comment: Maybe you should try changing `pdf = open("pdfs/" + (name), 'wb')` to `pdf = open("pdfs/"+name+".pdf", 'wb')` if you're missing an extension.

Comment: @DatHydroGuy Why so ? a bit is a bit, so _of course_ you can create a pdf file from a pdf binary content without any special lib.

Comment: @aeratedfrisbee you should check the response status code and the content type header to make sure you got what you expect before saving it to disk.

Comment: @bruno-desthuilliers You're right! I completely missed that the original files were already in .pdf format - I thought it was a HTML to PDF conversion we were talking about. I have removed my original comment to avoid confusion. Apologies.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers how do I do that?

Comment: `res.info()['Content-Type']`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers The content type is text/html. How do i change it to pdf?

Comment: If the content type is text/html then either the server is not doing it's job properly (setting a wrong content-type header) __or__ - more probably - you really got text/html content instead of the expected pdf. Maybe you could actually check the content itself and find out by yourself ? Oh and yes: did you check the status code ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers The status code is 200. I tried opening the downloaded file with Brackets: it shows the html code for the page. Any way to fix that?

Comment: I thinks you're not building the final url the right way - perhaps reading the html content you got could give you a hint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say exactly where's the error in your code - possibly the way you build the pdf url actually (or at least that would be my first bet) -, but using python-requests and using the root url only ("http://papers.xtremepapers.com") as base url it seems to work fine (at least the content-types are the expected application/pdf). The following script *should* work (minus possible typos and whatnot - I didn't test the whole script, not needing those pdfs xD)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ROOT_URL = 'http://papers.xtremepapers.com'
PAGE_URL = ROOT_URL + '/CIE/Cambridge%20International%20A%20and%20AS%20Level/Chemistry%20%289701%29/'

page = requests.get(PAGE_URL)
soup = bs(page.text)
urls = []

for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    href = link.get('href')
    if not (href and href.endswith('.pdf')):
        continue

    # builds a working absolute url
    url = ROOT_URL + href
    # only keeps the filename part as, well, filename
    name = href.split('/')[-1]
    print("url: {} - name : {}".format(url, name))

    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        # this will raise if not 200
        r.raise_for_status()
        # check the content type and raise if not ok
        if r.headers["Content-Type"] != "application/pdf":
            raise ValueError("unexpected content type '{}'".format(r.headers["Content-Type"]))

    except Exception as e:
        print("{} failed : {}".format(url, e))
        continue

    with open("pdfs/" + (name), 'wb') as pdf:
        pdf.write(r.content)
    print("{} ok".format(name))

print("Done")
```